# Run ansible playbook only to active hosts

Tags: automation, ansible

Is there any way I can run my ansible playbook so it only gets executed for currently active hosts?

Would really help out.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a ping on your hosts and save the ones who answer to run other tasks...

> ```
> - name: check reachable hosts
>   hosts: all
>   gather_facts: no
>   tasks:
>     - command: ping -c1 {{ inventory_hostname }}
>       delegate_to: localhost
>       register: ping_result
>       ignore_errors: yes
>     - group_by: key=reachable
>       when: ping_result|success
> ```

And then, run a new task for the new set of hosts.

> ```
> - name: your actual play
>   hosts: reachable
>   gather_facts: yes
>   tasks:
>     - debug: msg="this is {{ ansible_hostname }}"
> ```

Source: http://www.googlinux.com/ansible-run-play-only-on-reachable-host/